# Object oriented approach in android

Tags: java, android, xml, oop, object

I am trying to create a game as a self-development project in Android. Its going to get pretty complicated, so I thought I should get some advice. I know there are many approaches to one solution, however, any help in advising if my approach is right/wrong or how can I make it better is deeply appreciated.

I am trying to design a medieval age strategy game, like kingdoms, civilizations, etc.

Here is my structure so far of the project:

```
A main java class called Units.java with basic attributes like HitPoints, Attack, etc.
A few other classes called Quarry.java, SwordsMan.java, Archer.Java which extends Units.java
A main activity called Game.java which extends Activity class and will create instances of SwordsMan.java, Archer.java, Quarry.java
```

Now, I have an xml file called data.xml which stores in node format, the data for every thing. Here's a code snippet from the XML file:

```
<building id="0" name="Barracks" hp="1000" attack="0" armor="3" range="0">
   <cost wood="175"/>
      <unit id="0" name="Archer" hp="70" attack="13" armor="1" range="4">
        <cost food="60" gold="20"/>
      </unit>
</building>
```

So now, I'm using parsing this XML file in a method called by the contructor of the class Archer.java ... which uses SAX parser and pulls the data with the start elements of  and attribute name = "Archer".

Am I doing it right? Or is my approach totally wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, but why are you using XML for storage?
Why don't you just save the info in fields or something...

Comment: you could be right im not sure, i make games and i use opengl and keep everything in classes, im sort of a beginner, i saw your last one, i never used saxparser but good luck, theres plenty of different approaches to make games

Comment: I don't know why I'm using XML to save info... Maybe coz it gets saved in a node format. I wanted to use simple database for that, however, a friend suggested using XML.
What is a better approach? Is using XML a fairly good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OO design of your .java files looks great.

XML would be a fine idea for making saved files, if that is your intent.  I wouldn't parse the whole thing in the constructor for Archer.java, though - that seems rather arbitrary.  I suggest a separate class specifically for working with saved files.

As for XML vs a database, it depends on how you intent to use the saved data.  If you read the whole thing in or write it all out at once, either could be appropriate.  Saving an XML file to the SD card would make it easy to share a saved game.  If it's something you foresee changing only parts of to save and restore the state of an active game, then you should use a database, since with XML you would have to re-write the entire file each time.

Remember that in Android your app should handle being terminated at any time (e.g. if the user gets a phone call in the middle of a game).  Then it should provide a nice user experience when restarted, without losing the game's progress.